# How to stop reloading fragment

Tags: android, android-fragments

I know this question asked many times. But I didn't get the asnswer. I have a layout which contains two Tabs. When I switch the tabs they are reloading every time. Many people suggest to use `viewpager`. But I know nothing about `viewPager`. My project is almost completed.

My layout code:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_devices);

    mPreferences = getSharedPreferences(PreferencesManager.SCOPE,
            MODE_PRIVATE);

    mBundle = getIntent().getExtras();

    try {
        rl = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.mainLayout);
        //((Object) rl).setOffscreenPageLimit(2);
        fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        ActionBar bar = getActionBar();
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(TAB_NAME1).setTabListener(this));
        bar.addTab(bar.newTab().setText(TAB_NAME2).setTabListener(this));

        bar.setNavigationMode(ActionBar.NAVIGATION_MODE_TABS);
        bar.show();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }

}

FragmentMine fram1;
FragmentTransaction fragMentTra = null;
FragmentAll fram2;


@Override
public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

    if (tab.getText().equals(TAB_NAME1)) {
        try {
            rl.removeAllViews();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        fram1 = new FragmentMine();
        fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
        fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram1);
        fragMentTra.commit();
    } else if (tab.getText().equals(TAB_NAME2)) {
        try {
            rl.removeAllViews();
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
        fram2 = new FragmentAll();
        fragMentTra.addToBackStack(null);
        fragMentTra = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
        fragMentTra.add(rl.getId(), fram2);
        fragMentTra.commit();
    }
}
```

How to stop reloading tabs when switched?

Comment: *How to stop reloading tabs when switched?* -  you stop creating new instances of those fragments and then attaching them to the container.

Comment: can you explain briefly @Luksprog

Comment: Every time you select a tab you create a new fragment and you add it to the container. If you want to keep those fragments then store them and use attach/detach transactions.

Comment: @Luksprog and make them singletons. :)

Answer (score 1):

Every time onTabSelected() is called you are instantiating a new Fragment. 
You should make use of a FragmentPagerAdapter.

Check: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/FragmentPagerAdapter.html

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by `Rik`, you are instantiating a new `Fragment` by:

```
fram1 = new FragmentMine();
```

You need to save the state of your fragment by overriding `onSaveInstanceState()`:

```
@Override 
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
    // Whatever is there to save
}
```

Comment: *Fragments are supposed to be singletons* - no, they are not, especially that one of the restrictions on them is to have the default constructor visible. If you're referring to the newInstance() method that is another convention.

Comment: @Luksprog Well, I am not as experienced as you are. So what's the right way to use a fragment?

Answer (score 0):

Using this class helps you for work onViewCreated only one time

```
abstract class BaseFragment<B : ViewDataBinding>(
    private val viewID: Int,
) : Fragment() {

    var dataBinding: B? = null
    private var isPageLoaded = false

    abstract fun onViewCreated()

    override fun onViewCreated(view: View, savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState)
        if (!isPageLoaded) {
            onViewCreated()
            isPageLoaded = true
        }
    }

    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?,
    ): View? {
        if (dataBinding == null) {
            performDataBinding(inflater, container)
        }
        return dataBinding?.root
    }

    private fun performDataBinding(
        inflater: LayoutInflater,
        container: ViewGroup?,
    ) {
        dataBinding = DataBindingUtil.inflate(
            inflater, viewID, container, false
        )
        dataBinding?.let {
            it.lifecycleOwner = this
        }
    }
}
```

and use this class in your fragment like this :

```
class HomeFragment : BaseFragment<FragmentHomeBinding>(R.layout.fragment_home) {
...
}
```